# translateX with a link and a <i>

Tags: css, transition, translate-animation

I'de like to make a short translateX transition of 5px to the right. 
I think I have a problem with the display. All other transitions work only this one doesn't...

Here is my code:

```css
#content a.shake {
  display: inline-block;

  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

#content a.shake i {
  display: inline-block;
}
#content a.shake:hover {
  display: inline-block;

  -webkit-tranform: translateX(5px);
  -moz-tranform: translateX(5px);
  -o-tranform: translateX(5px);
  -ms-tranform: translateX(5px);
  tranform: translateX(5px);
}
```

```html
<a class="shake" href="#">Choisissez un prestataire<i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
```

Comment: Works just fine. Is your problem because of the missing `s` in `transform` ?

Comment: Shame on me! Thanks @Abhitalks that was exactly because I miss a "s"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo : transform, not tranform

tranform: translateX(5px);